# Embedding UIWebView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview

First, I would start by saying I have searched through S/O and I haven't found any topic that really solved it. Yes it got embedded but the UIScrollView didn't scroll.

Secondly, I know Apple docs used to say its not recommended, but it is possible, and the Apple News app does exactly what I need to be done.

What I want is to show an article, but I wanna show the 'featured image' and 'title' without making an additional request, all I want to fetch is the article body.

So, I wanna create a UIScrollView, add subviews which includes the subview and make sure all scroll just the same way Apple news app does it. Here's a visual representation.

```
|- UIViewController
|-- UIScrollView
|------ UIImageView
|------ UIView
|---------- UILabel
|------ UIWebView
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Pretty sure the Apple news app doesn't use a `UIWebView`

Comment: They do. I inspected the app. They run a UIWebView under the featured image and time stamp

Comment: Fair enough, if you want to outer scrollview to scroll then you should disable scrolling on the web view and make it tall enough that it doesn't have to scroll to show all its content

Comment: What did you try so far? what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have successfully embedded the UIWebController in the UIScrollView. I have succeeded in disabling scrolling in the UIWebView, and I have pretty much nailed it, I have even used `sizeThatFits:CGZero` on the web view so it expands to the height of the web page. The only issue I have however is, the UIScrollView doesn't scroll down. Its just like a static view, no scrolling nada. I have checked that the UIScrollView has scrolling enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully set the height of the `UIWebView` to the height of the web page and and the 3 direct subviews of your `UIScrollview` are correctly placed on top of each other than you probably just did not set the `contentSize` on the `UIScrollView` correctly.

The `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize.height` should be equal to the `UIImageView` height plus the `UIView` height plus the `UIWebView` height.

So, have a look at the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` and you probably find the cause of the problem.

If that does not solve your problem, have a look at this [blogpost](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-a-uiwebviews-height-to-the-height-of-its-html-content-using-auto-layout/) that I wrote recently. It describes how to achieve exactly what you need. It uses an approach using AutoLayout. It looks as if you are not using AutoLayout but maybe it helps you anyway.